# Windows are maximised below taskbar

Tags: windows, windows-7

I've tried googling and the only suggestion I found was ending the explorer.exe process, which hasn't made a difference. At the moment I have the taskbar on auto-hide but it's not much of a solution for me. I also tried changing DPI and the resolution, still no difference.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your Windows taskbar has been moved to the top of the screen and you want to move it back to the bottom. Am I right? If that's the case, here's the solution:

1. Right-click on the taskbar and make sure that "Lock the taskbar" is unselected in the context menu.
2. Left-click on the taskbar drag it down to the bottom of the screen (holding the left mouse button).
3. Right-click on the taskbar again and select "Lock the taskbar" to prevent the problem from recurring.

Comment: I'm trying my best to explain it. The bottom of applications are hidden by the taskbar when it's locked, they are only fully visible if I resize the window or auto-hide the taskbar. I didn't notice when exactly this happened.

Comment: @PaulaTaggart, it might help to understand which applications you are using in which you specifically observe this behavior. If you right-click on the taskbar, click "Properties" and then uncheck "Auto-hide the taskbar" and check "Lock the taskbar" you should observe that most native Windows apps behave properly. For example, if you maximize an instance of Notepad, both of the scrollbars should be visible (along bottom and right edges). Are there specific examples of applications that fail this test?

Comment: All applications are affected, any application i use that can be maximised has this problem. I've already tried locking the taskbar-it was locked when this behaviour started. Sorry this has been going on for weeks and I'd forgotten I'd tried that.

Comment: Paula, a person on [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/i-need-the-taskbar-always-on-top-on-windows-7/c3a6577c-bab7-4cdc-8156-24da626f8047?page=2) seems to have found a solution. It involves restoring all of your windows ("un-maximizing" them) and then re-maximizing them with the taskbar visible. Another thought that comes to mind... this sounds like the sort of defect that Microsoft may have patched during the Windows 7 product lifespan. Are you up to date on Windows updates?